# C++ assignment operator resolving

Tags: c++, assignment-operator, member-hiding

Consider the following code:

```
struct A
{
    void foo( const char * ) { cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; }
    A & operator = ( const A &  ) { cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; return * this; }
};


struct B : public A
{
    void foo( const char * ) { cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; }
    A & operator = ( const A & other ) { cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; return * this; }
};
```

Then when we call this members:

```
B b;

b.foo( "hehe" );
b = b;
```

Will be printed:

```
void B::foo( const char *)
A& A::operator=(const A&)
```

Question: why B::foo hides A::foo, but B::operator= doesn't?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you see is not a hiding problem at all. You did not create an assignment operator to assign B into B, therefore the compiler created one for you. The one created by the compiler is calling assignment operator of A.

Therefore, if your question "Question: why B::foo hides A::foo, but B::operator= doesn't?" should be read "How is operator= different from an ordinary function", the difference is compiler will provide one for you if you do not write your own.

Comment: Ok, as I understand, compiler generates the following code for B:

B & operator = ( const B & b )
{
 A::operator = ( b );
 return *this;
}

But if we have virtual "A::operator =", then "B::operator =" should be invoked, because it overrides "A::operator =".

But it's not.

Comment: virtuality does not matter here. A compiler generated copy always calls base class implementation. That said, having operator = virtual rarely makes sense anyway. Cf. http://icu-project.org/docs/papers/cpp_report/the_assignment_operator_revisited.html